# Entrypoint is not a Dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have been reading more than 10 similiar question for this error and still cant solve my problem

[image]

im trying delete .idea and still cant solve it,trying add content root in my project too, but the problem isn`t solved, can you help me?, thanks

Comment: Try typing only *lib\main.dart* instead of *D:\dani\...*.

Comment: same error @enzo Error: Entrypoint file not found at lib\main.dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the warning 'Entrypoint is not a dart file' my main.dart was also showing the code in just one plain color (white) with no intellisense whatsoever.
After deleting .ideal/ folder and dart_tools, uninstalling/re-instaling android studio, and other attempts, there was no luck and no solution on google addressing this very error message so i decided to try this:

After saving my work

1. Go To File in Android Studio Menu at the top
2. Manage IDE Settings
3. Restore Default Settings

It will redownload android sdk and setup everything as new.
Paste your codes from previous projects and ride on!

Comment: Finally, a solution that worked for me! 
Thank you

Comment: this is not a very good idea, you will loose everything in will be lost including plugis